# s(n)printf prints more characters than format specifier specifies

Tags: c, embedded, stdio

I am encountering a curious issue with `sprintf` on an embedded system (Libelium Waspmote, similar to Arduino) where sprintf is outputting more characters than given by the format specifier. In this particular instance I am using `%02X` to output the hexadecimal value of bytes in an array. However on some bytes, instead of writing 2 characters, 4 are being written, with `FF` being prefixed before the actual byte value. `snprintf` behaves similarly, except that it respects the buffer size specified and just prints the prefix.

For reference, here is the code snippet printing the array contents:

```
char *pduChars = (char *) malloc(17*sizeof(char));
pduData.toChar(pduChars);
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    char asciiCharsS[5];
    char asciiCharsSN[3];
    int printedS = sprintf(asciiCharsS, "%02X", pduChars[i]);
    int printedSN = snprintf(asciiCharsSN, 3, "%02X", pduChars[i]);
    USB.print(printedS);
    USB.print(" ");
    USB.print(printedSN);
    USB.print(" ");
    USB.print(asciiCharsS);
    USB.print(" ");
    USB.print(asciiCharsSN);
    USB.println(" ");
}
```

And the output from that snippet (abridged to only the erroneous bytes):
The actual byte sequence should be 0x00 0xFC 0xFF 0xFF 0x48 0xA5 0x33 0x51

`sprintf snprintf sprintf Buffer snprintf Buffer`

`…

2   2   00  00

4   4   FFFC    FF

4   4   FFFF    FF

4   4   FFFF    FF

2   2   48  48

4   4   FFA5    FF

2   2   33  33

2   2   51  51`

Am I overlooking something here or might this be a platform-specific issue relating to the implementation of `s(n)printf`?

Comment: Could it be that on your platform `char` is 2 bytes? Note that the 2 in `%02X` is the minimum length, not the maximum length.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` returns `1` so it seems that is not the case.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always one. That is defined by the standard. But that doesn't mean it's one byte. In fact, `sizeof` doesn't give the number of bytes, it shows the size relative to the size of `char`.

Comment: Remember to `free()` the memory allocated to `pduChars`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your implementation is using **signed** chars. The format `"%X"` expects **unsigned** values. Cast or use `unsigned char` instead.

```
/* cast */
int printedS = sprintf(asciiCharsS, "%02X", (unsigned char)pduChars[i]);
int printedSN = snprintf(asciiCharsSN, 3, "%02X", (unsigned char)pduChars[i]);
```

or

```
/* use unsigned char */
unsigned char *pduChars = malloc(17); /* cast is, at best, redundant */
                                      /* sizeof (char) is, by definition, 1 */
```

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier modifiers you are using are only used for padding. In case the value's number of symbols exceeds the specified value, the whole string will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

%02X is for padding... it will not omit...
so in case your value is greater than specified value then whole string will be printed